# read number from a text file and replace with a something else

Tags: c#, io

My text file looks like this

mytext.txt

```
1. This is line one
2. This is line two
3. This is line three
.....
```

Now I want to read mytext.txt using c# and then replace those lines like this and save it to a text file.

```
Number. This is line one
Number. This is line two
Number. This is line three
.....
```

Comment: So you want us to write all the code for you? That's not going to happen, show your efforts.

Comment: I think it did happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the code, but explain what each step does so that you can learn from it:

```
// assume that System.IO is included (in a using statement)
// reads the file, changes all leading integers to "Number", and writes the changes
void rewriteNumbers(string file)
{
    // get the lines from the file
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    // for each line, do:
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        // trim all number characters from the beginning of the line, and
        // write "Number" to the beginning
        lines[i] = "Number" + lines[i].TrimStart('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
    }
    // write the changes back to the file
    File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
}
```

Comment: antonijn's solution is another way to look at the problem: find the first period, then remove all characters before it. that would also work...

Comment: So you're not the downvoter?

Comment: I don't have 125 reputation; I can't be the downvoter...

Comment: Yep that's a very good point